# Why does the Evernote thumbnail request return 404?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, evernote

I am trying to create a list of notes, that includes the note's name, url, and thumbnail. I can successfully get the metadata, and content data with 
`NoteStore.findNotesMetadata` and  `NoteStore.getNote` and I can construct the note's url, but I can't get the thumbnail data. I am constructing the request get the image with:

```
import { Evernote } from 'evernote';
import request from 'request-promise';

...

async getThumbnail(noteGuid) {
    const params = {
      method: 'GET',
      data: { auth: this.authorization.credentials.access_token },
      url: `https://sandbox.evernote.com/shard/${this.user.shardId}/thm/note/${noteGuid}/`,
    };        
    try {
      const result = await request(params);
      console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('err', err);
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

The request is failing with a 404. Is there something wrong with how I am formatting my request or URL?

Comment: what happens if you create the url (still using string interpolation) but outside of the async function? you would then pass that parameter as the url to your async fucntion

Comment: @Omarjmh it produces the same 404 error.

Comment: Try logging in to Evernote (sandbox) and visiting the url you get after interpolation - do you still get a 404?

Comment: @akhaku Yes, the Evernote 404 page. The page says, 'Page not found
The location you provided is not valid. (/shard/s1/thm/note/noteGUID/)'. Which is what led me to believe that I'm building the wrong URL. I know the shard and noteGUID are right, because I am using them to get the note's content.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is correct but the thumbnail request isn't a `GET` to that endpoint. It's a `POST` with the auth token as named param in the body.

See this doc page for how to build a correctly-formatted request:
https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/thumbnails.php

(In your case it might be as simple as changing the method to `POST`.)